# Visual Studio EF now showing model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with Visual Studio: I can't add Entity Framework models to the project.

I have EF installed https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8cd5yb8sjm362m/nu%20get.png, but still no model is shown: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tcvuyo119ksjqvf/diagram.png .

I don't know what is the problem. I used the EF before and it worked but after windows reinstall i can't use it anymore.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 REL

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried to the same thing, I have the VS2013, Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1.

And that EDMX model class template is there for me.

Could you not just try and update your VS2013 to a later version.

Got to **Tools**, **Extensions** and **Updates**

Check out the Product Updates, and update to VS2013 Update 2.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I had this problem for weeks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your question may need additional information in order to provide the proper solution. I am sure you are aware of the concept of code first for Entity Framework, this involving you to create your model class first then from here mapping the model class to the dbcontext and from here you will have a db generated (clearly, a none detailed synopsis). Additionally, if you are trying to map an existing database to your project try to use EF object generator which is displayed within this screen shot as the second option from the top https://www.dropbox.com/s/tcvuyo119ksjqvf/diagram.png. Again, this are assumptions with very little information provided. If this does not steer you in the right direction please comment with more specifics and I will be more than happy to assist.

Comment: It should still be there. EF Code First is great, but not what he is wanting to use.